# ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer affect the data outside the clipping rect

Tags: node.js, winapi, console, ffi, windows-console

I'm using nodejs with ffi to call winapi. I've wrapped some of functions that used to control console.

```js
let kernel32 = ffi.Library('kernel32.dll', {
// ...
    'ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW': [ BOOL, [ HANDLE, PSMALL_RECT, PSMALL_RECT, COORD, PCHAR_INFO ]],
// ...
});
const wincon = {
// ...
    ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer: (handle, target, clip, dest, fill) => {
        let sr = ref.alloc(SMALL_RECT, target);
        let cr = clip == null ? ref.NULL : ref.alloc(SMALL_RECT, clip);
        let ci = ref.alloc(CHAR_INFO, fill);
        return {
            ret: kernel32.ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW(handle, sr, cr, new COORD(dest), ci) != 0
        };
    },
// ...
};
```

The codes above is how I declare the `ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer`.

```js
const ui = {
// ...
    log: (hout, region) => {
        return {
            hout: hout,
            region: region,
            log: function (old_strs) {
                let strs = [];
                let width = region.R - region.L + 1;
                old_strs.forEach(s => {
                    while (s.length > width) {
                        strs.push(s.slice(0, width));
                        s = s.slice(width);
                    }
                    if (s.length > 0) {
                        strs.push(s);
                    }
                });
                wincon.ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer(this.hout, this.region, this.region, { X: this.region.L, Y: this.region.T - strs.length }, { C: 32, A: wincon.BACKGROUND_WHITE + wincon.BACKGROUND_INTENSIVE });
                for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; ++i) {
                    wincon.WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(this.hout, strs[i], { X: this.region.L, Y: this.region.B + 1 - strs.length + i });
                }
            }
        };
    },
}
// other file
let batLogRegion = { L: 60, T: 30, R: 119, B: 59 };
let batlog = ui.log(hstdout, batLogRegion);
batlog.log(info.log.slice(logged));
```

The codes above is how I use it.

However, when I log a bunch of things, the text scroll to the top of the console, instead of being clipped. And after more calls, the text above the 30 row are still moving up.

It's not because the log contains too much text. Actually it has less than 20 rows.

The problem shouldn't because of the wrong definition or calling method, as a lot of other functions work fine.

So there should be some problems of my use of `ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer`.

Can any one help me?

Some pictures:

The clipping rect is { 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 1 }(if the window is { 0, 0, 1, 1 }), and the text is moved to the top.

[use scan to generate much text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7voEP.png)

[after doing sth. the text above is still going up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqqtd.png)

Comment: Could you please show the screenshots you get and the results you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I could produce this issue, I am using the following sample in C++:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void log(HANDLE hStdout, vector<wstring> old_strs, SMALL_RECT region)
{
    COORD coordDest;
    CHAR_INFO chiFill;
    vector<wstring> strs;
    size_t width = region.Right - region.Left;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < old_strs.size(); i++)
    {
        wstring s = old_strs[i];
        while (s.length() > width)
        {
            strs.push_back(s.substr(0, width-1));
            s = s.substr(width-1);
        }
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            strs.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    coordDest.X = region.Left;
    coordDest.Y = region.Top - strs.size();

    chiFill.Attributes = BACKGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED;
    chiFill.Char.UnicodeChar = 32;

    if (!ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW(
        hStdout,         // screen buffer handle 
        &region, // scrolling rectangle 
        &region,   // clipping rectangle 
        coordDest,       // top left destination cell 
        &chiFill))       // fill character and color
    {
        printf("ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    DWORD len = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++)
    {
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hStdout, strs[i].c_str(), strs[i].length(), { region.Left,region.Bottom + 1 - (SHORT)strs.size() + (SHORT)i }, &len);
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = NULL;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
        int k = (i > 9 ? 116 : 117);
        char x = (i > 25 ? 'a' : 'A');
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            printf("%c", x + i % 26);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("GetStdHandle failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    vector<wstring> old_strs = { L"this is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long string" };
    for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
        old_strs.push_back(std::to_wstring(i));
    SMALL_RECT batLogRegion = { 60,30,119,59 };
    log(hStdout,old_strs, batLogRegion);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

When the `strs` obtained by the `old_strs` slice contains more than 30 (`batLogRegion.Bottom - batLogRegion.Top + 1 = 30`) lines of string, although `ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW` will not affect other areas outsize the clipping rect, but in `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW`: `region.Bottom + 1 - strs.size() + i` is above the `region`. So, you may need to re-determine the size of your clipping rect according to your needs (strs' size), like:

```
if ((int)(region.Bottom - region.Top + 1 - strs.size())< 0)
{
    region.Bottom = region.Top + strs.size() - 1;
}
```

UPDATE:

Added a judgment, when the length of the strs is greater than the height of the clipping rect, the string that exceeds top is not printed.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void log(HANDLE hStdout, vector<wstring> old_strs, SMALL_RECT region)
{
    COORD coordDest;
    CHAR_INFO chiFill;
    vector<wstring> strs;
    size_t width = region.Right - region.Left;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < old_strs.size(); i++)
    {
        wstring s = old_strs[i];
        while (s.length() > width)
        {
            strs.push_back(s.substr(0, width-1));
            s = s.substr(width-1);
        }
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            strs.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    coordDest.X = region.Left;
    coordDest.Y = region.Top - strs.size();
    
    chiFill.Attributes = BACKGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED;
    chiFill.Char.UnicodeChar = 32;

    if (!ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW(
        hStdout,         // screen buffer handle 
        &region, // scrolling rectangle 
        &region,   // clipping rectangle 
        coordDest,       // top left destination cell 
        &chiFill))       // fill character and color
    {
        printf("ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer failed %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    DWORD len = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((int)(region.Bottom - region.Top + 1 - strs.size()+i) < 0)
            continue;
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hStdout, strs[i].c_str(), strs[i].length(), { region.Left,region.Bottom + 1 - (SHORT)strs.size() + (SHORT)i }, &len);
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = NULL;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
        int k = (i > 9 ? 116 : 117);
        char x = (i > 25 ? 'a' : 'A');
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            printf("%c", x + i % 26);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("GetStdHandle failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    vector<wstring> old_strs = { L"this is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long string" };
    vector<wstring> old_strs2 = { L"this is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long string" };

    SMALL_RECT batLogRegion = { 60,30,119,59 };
    for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
        old_strs.push_back(std::to_wstring(i));

    log(hStdout, old_strs, batLogRegion);
    Sleep(1000);
    log(hStdout, old_strs2, batLogRegion);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll try adding the check and test it again.

Comment: If the issue is as I said, then the problem may appear in the `COORD.Y` parameter of `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW` instead of `ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW`

Comment: It seems not because of this. This will add some text above the clipping rect, but the following function call won't move those text up. But after reproducing the problem, I notice that the text above is till going upper and upper.

Comment: I've add some pictures.

Comment: After solving the what you mentioned, the problem does disappear. But why before solving it, the scroll function will move text above the clipping rect?

Comment: It may because `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW` also prints out the string outside the cutting rectangle. Do you print all strings together every time?

Comment: When strs.size is larger than `region.Bottom-region.Left+1` in a call, the `COORD.Y` parameter in `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW` will be less than clipping rect.top, so the string will be print above the clipping rect.

Comment: No. I only print the new logs. I use the variable logged to save how many rows of text have been printed, and every time I scroll the old texts and print the newly added texts.

Comment: Try to copy the `log()` function to `logwithoutWrite()`, then comment `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`, then call `log` once and then call `logwithoutWrite` in the following call to check if the problem can be reproduced. BTW, does each new logs get `strs.length>region.B-region.T+1`?

Comment: No. For the picture I provided, Firstly it logs an extreme long text(those html), then it logs less than 10 rows. It's weird that the text at the top are moved by the scroll function.

Comment: What's more, you can find that in the second picture the row "You cast Scan" is moved up and mixed with the old text, creating a longger text. It seems that the above text is moved up, while the blank is not. So the scrolled text cover the old text, while the scrolled blank leave old text unchanged.

Comment: I can't reproduce `ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer` affect the data outside the clipping rect, but using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter can reproduce text mixing(that is, overwrite on the original text). I added a judgment, when the length of the strs is greater than the height of the clipping rect, the string that exceeds top is not printed. This should be better than the previous method.